Call to a member function getGroup() on null
I created an administrator view for my improvementplans.
Locally everything works fine, but I get an error on my production site.

All my other views are working fine, but the one for my improvement plans not.
I checked the code inside my component, but I couldn't find and rule that says getGroup
Does anyone know where to look and what this error could mean?
Its weird because it looks bound to my view as the others views are working fine.
Im using:
PHP 8.1.29
Joomla ‎4.4.6

If your local development environment is on Windows where there is not normally any case sensitivity, A is the same as a, then the likely problem is that in your code you have a class defined with either an uppercase or lowercase letter when it should be the other way around.
When you move the code to the production site then it is most likely a flavour of linux where case matters and then your class is not found, thus the Object is not created and whatever getGroup() is supposed to be found in doesn't exist, it is null, hence the message. Look at the Class, Namespace and Use statements for an incorrect case letter in the file where getGroup() is located.
If I am right about your local development environment being on Windows and you would like to prevent this issue you can make Windows folders case sensitive so that this issue would appear in development and not when you get to production. I wrote about how to do it here, https://notes.irataweb.com.au/how-to-programming/developer-tools-how-to/make-windows-10-folders-case-sensitive
